# If Statement to get the alert for no Coordinates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have a data of cities in the Jason. Some of them have coordiantes and some of them don't have coordinates. I am trying to use if statement so that in case there are no coordinates of the city. The system will prompt alert.

```
if(coordinates!==null){
             alert("inside")
            console.log(id,coordinates);
            var coord= coordinates.substring(1, coordinates.length - 1).split(",");
            console.log(coord)
    IndividualMarker(coord,name);
            }
    else
        {
           alert("no coordinates found")
        }
```

if(coordinates!==null) seems not to be working . coz i am getting alert inside with nulls too.
The data in the coordinates is like  [-12.1625,7.9794]

Anyone suggest me how to implement iff in that case

Comment: Apparently coordinates isn't `null`, but probably just an empty string or `undefined`, or even the string `"null"`, which isn't the same as `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a test snippet to check your if statement?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  var data = [{
    id: 1,
    coords: [-12.1625, 7.9794]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    coords: []
  }, {
    id: 3,
    coords: null
  }, {
    id: 4,
    coords: 'null'
  }]

  $scope.validResults = [];
  $scope.invalidResults = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    checkCoordinates(data[i]);
  }

  function checkCoordinates(item) {
    if (item && item.coords && item.coords.length && item.coords != 'null') {
      console.log('valid coords: ', item);
      $scope.validResults.push(item);
    } else {
      console.log('invalid coords: ', item);
      $scope.invalidResults.push(item);
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <h3>Valid</h3>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in validResults">
      <span>id: {{item.id}}</span><br />
      <span>coords: {{item.coords}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <hr/>

  <h3>Invalid</h3>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in invalidResults">
      <span>id: {{item.id}}</span><br />
      <span>coords: {{item.coords}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```